# Java DateFormat.

Tags: java

Какого вида должна быть дата, при dateStyle=2. Не нашел ответа в JavaDocs.

```
        private int dateStyle;
        private Locale USED_LOCALE = Locale.getDefault ();

    public Calendar toCalendar (String dateString) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance (dateStyle, USED_LOCALE);
        Calendar calendar = dateFormat.getCalendar ();
        calendar.setTime (dateFormat.parse (dateString));
        return calendar;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ.

```
dateString="11 апреля 2018 г."
```

[Вот свойства для руской локализации](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/ru-RU/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

В то поле пишут обычно не число, а константу в виде SHORT, LONG и т.д. Имена констант и их числовые значения приведены [в этой таблице](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.text.DateFormat.AM_PM_FIELD).

Конкретно 2 соответствует [DEFAULT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#DEFAULT), оно же MEDIUM. В локали en_US будет формат "Jun 30, 2009", в локали de_DE будет "30.06.2009" ([тут подглядел](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html)). В локали ru_RU, наверное, так же как в немецкой.